# How to add signature to URL

Tags: java, urlconnection

I'm making a UrlConnection and it requires a signature using SHA1.
I have already generate the signature but I don't know how to append it to the connection.

Here are my codes:

```
String url = domain + path 
           +"?api_key="+DEVELOPER_API_KEY
           +"&timestamp="+time
           +"&username="+givenName;                        
urlToRequest = new URL(url);             
urlconnection = (HttpURLConnection)urlToRequest.openConnection();
urlconnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

I don't know where to place my signature. I've tried to append it in the url like

```
+"signature="+signature;
```

but it doesn't work.
So how should I do it?
Thank you guys.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, appending it to your `url` should work just fine, from your example however you seem to have forgot an ampersand.

`url = url + "&signature=" + signature;`